# PHP store result of a dynamic variable every 24 hours

Tags: php, json

I searched for a long time but did not find this anywhere.
So let's say I make an API call and put some data in a Variable.

```
   <?php
$coinData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD'), true); 
        
    
    $testVar = $coinData['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'];

    
    echo $testVar;
     
   ?>
```

Now I got the actual realtime value of the price of Bitcoin in my `$testVar` variable. This value is changing all the time.

How can I make a "snapshot" every 24 Hours of this variable, and store this Data Value? I can't find anything on how to "snapshot" the value out of a Dynamic Variable.

For example, in 1 hour I want to take a "snapshot" out of the variable `$testVar`, at this time the value is `5322.15` . Now I want to store this exact value as `5322.15`  automatically, to use it later.

Comment: You can use crontab/cronjob.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I think I will do it with a cronjob. But do you know how to snapshot a dynamic value? I did not find anything on that

Comment: The snapshot as you call it happens when you run the job from cron.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a cron job to run every 24 hours, and then write each day's value as a new row in a database table. For example along these lines:

```
id int NOT NULL,
timestamp datetime NOT NULL,
current_value decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
```

The your cron job would look something like:

```
<?php
$db= mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);//connect to db
$coinData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD'), true); 
$current_value = $coinData['RAW']['BTC']['USD']['PRICE'];
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO currency_values (current_value, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->execute([$current_value, $timestamp]);
```